# Java packages for interfaces, abstract classes and implementations

Tags: java, package

Ahoi!

Even though I only have a small number of classes, I'd like to hear your suggestions about packages.

I do have an `GenericDAO` interface, an abstract `GenericHibernateDAO` class, an `UserDAO` interface and finally a `UserDAOHibernate` class. They're roughly sorted by how general they are.
I'll certainly add more interfaces like `UserDAO` and `UserDAOHibernate`, so they will need their own package.

I also have a `GenericEntity` interface, an abstract `LongEntity` class (which needs a better name btw.) and the `User` class. I'll add more classes like the `User` class lateron.

*How many packages would you recommend and which names would you use?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages your create depends on some factors.  For example, if your API makes use of package-private scoping, you might arrange them differently than if the API is more open.

You can create a package like

`com.company.app.domain`

for your entities (you can also have model, entity, or anything else that makes sense, instead of domain, for your app)

You can create

`com.company.app.dao`

for your Daos.

If you want to restrict how your model objects talk to each other, you could create a package for each type (like User), with the DAO and services in the package.  Or you can alternatively create a `.user.service` package.

Without knowing your application design, I can't really say more, other than don't create a complicated package hierarchy if you don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I recommend using 50 billion packages. Each class shall have its own package, but every package shall not have a class. And packages shall share the name of their class. And for those packages without a class, they shall be named by simply closing your eyes and slamming the keyboard.

Comment: Those names would be too easy to grasp. Recommend using UUIDs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Packaging classes and interfaces is an interesting topic.  Some people are in the camp of: "Class and class function visibility determine packaging" whereas others are in the camp of: "Package classes and interfaces based on functionality.

Personally, I do the latter.  In my book, packaging restrictions based on class/function visibility is a design issue.

For your example, I only see two:

```
what.ever.generic
what.ever.user
```

Comment: Where would I put UserDAO then? It's an interface and as such it's generic, but it is specific to the User DTO.
User is just a random class by the way, there are others like  Customer, Application etc.

Comment: Assuming UserDAO extends GenericDAO and that there are going to be many classes more classes implementing one of these:  GenericDAO goes in .generic and UserDAO goes in .user

Comment: It's more like GenericDAO, UserDAO (and User class), ApplicationDAO (and Application class), CustomerDAO. Using your schema I'd have to use packages for application and customer as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds too complicated to me.  (Yes, I read your previous question.)

I don't see why you have UserDAOHibernate when you have a generic DAO.

I'd do it this way:

```
package persistence;

public interface GenericDao<K extends Serializable, V> {
    List<V> find();
    V find(K key);
    K save(V value);
    void update(V value);
    void delete(V value);
}
```

I'd have a Hibernate implementation for this, but an instance for user would look like this:

```
GenericDaoImpl<Long, User> userDao = new GenericDaoImpl<Long, User>();
```

All that stuff about Entity is overkill in my opinion.

Comment: The `GenericDAO` specifies generic CRUD methods (which apply to all entities/classes), whereas `UserDAO` adds methods specific to the User class, such as `findByName()`. The `GenericHibernateDAO` is for convenience in all class specific hibernate DAOs which inherit from it.
I agree that the ENTITY/ID seems a little over the top, but it allows to easily replace `Long id` with `String id`.

Comment: No, that's what the key generic is for.

Comment: Your interface does not guarantee that K is actually a part of V, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I don't see any reason why it needs to.

Comment: At least with hibernate you'd want to have your object/class include an id (of a certain type). Which in this case should be of the same type as `K`.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely group classes by function and not by visibility or any implementation detail:

- Implementation changes (function should not), but do you want to move your classes to another package in that case?
- For classes, no-one ever asks *Should I put all String/Integer/Collection variables in a separate class?* But people seem to struggle more with package organization.

Comment: Still a package like `foo.dao.hibernate` makes it clear that the classes are DAOs specific to hibernate. They would remain in that package even though they might use hibernate v2, v3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use something to inject the implementations into your objects.  Use the interfaces as the private member types.

```
class MyObject
{
  private GenericDao meaningfulName;
  private UserDao meaningfulName;
}

blah.dao - DAO interfaces here.
blah.dao.hibernate - Hibernate implementation of DAO interfaces here.
blah.entity - GenericEntity here.  Abstract (i.e. base) implementations of
              interfaces here (LongEntity for example).
blah.entity.impl - Implementation of GenericEntity here.
blah.domain - Domain classes like User here.
```

Instead of `LongEntity` maybe use `BaseEntity`.

Comment: I don't quite see why I'd want to have both DAOs as private members?

Your package idea matches what I had in mind. Which seemed too complicated, that's why I asked here :)
Thanks for a new name for LongEntity. BaseEntity does not really reflect that is uses `Long id`.

Comment: private members of MyObject because they will be used exclusively by MyObject.  Make them private members of any class that needs them.

Comment: So `MyObject` is just some random class with business logic? Why would it need `GenericDAO` then, since this is already inherited by `UserDAO`?